# server side validation in the main view cause also validation in partial view, how to stop that?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, validation, razor

I have layout with login partial view (username, password and submit button) and models ( some controls and submit button)with validation(server side and client side) displayed in normal views (@RenderBody() in layout).

My problem is when do server side validation in any of my views it also validate the login partial view because it execute the httppost function of the login. how can I stop that??

login view controller

```
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult LogOn()
    {
        return PartialView();
    }

    //
    // POST: /Account/LogOn

    [HttpPut]
    public ActionResult LogOn(LogOnModel model)
    {            
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            if (MembershipService.ValidateUser(model.UserName, model.Password))
            {
                FormsService.SignIn(model.UserName, model.RememberMe);
                ViewBag.UserName = model.UserName;
            }
            else
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("", Resources.Account.Account.LoginFailureText);
            }
        }

        return PartialView(model);
    }
```

and model controller

```
public ActionResult MyModel()
    {
        ViewBag.DisplayThxMsg = false;
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult MyModel(Models.FeedbacksModel feedback)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            //do something
        }
        else{
           //do another thing
        }
        return View(feedback);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find your question very difficult to understand. Im guessing your problem is you have a login partial control displayed as part of site layout and is shown on all pages. So while submitting any page, the username password validation kicks in, and you want to prevent that.

Understand that all validation @ server - side happens while model binding, As properties are bound to the posted fields, the attributes on the fields are looked at and honored / catered to. So to prevent server side validation simply put the login partial view in *it's own form* so it is not sent while submitting other forms on the page.

In short have 2 forms - one form for login and one for feedback. Don't put all input fields in the same form.

If you still have validation errors after that, then it is because of other reasons like, type conversion problems. The default model binder will add some errors for basic type conversion issues (for example, passing a non-number for something which is an "int").The sample DataAnnotations model binder will fill model state with validation errors taken from the DataAnnotations attributes on your model.

*EDIT*

If you look at line number 125

```
 @using (Html.BeginForm()){Html.RenderAction("LogOn", "Account");}
```

You have the above code which will render the login form.
It will do so inside the other form at line 45

```
 <form id="form1" runat="server" method="post">
```

This has no end tag therefore it will encompass the whole document till `</html>`

You should change the structure from

```
<form id="form1" runat="server" method="post">
 @using (Html.BeginForm()){Html.RenderAction("LogOn", "Account");}
 </form
```

to

```
<form id="form1" runat="server" method="post">
 </form>
 @using (Html.BeginForm()){Html.RenderAction("LogOn", "Account");}
```

This line @using `(Html.BeginForm()){Html.RenderAction("LogOn", "Account");}` will render this form `<form id="LoginView1" action="LogOn">` and all child elements of it.

**LATEST EDIT**

In your layout page use this :
`@Html.Partial("~/Views/Shared/LogOnPartial.cshtml", new LogOnModel())`
instead of this :
`@Html.Action("LogOnPartial", "Account")`

The reason why it all works is, the `LogOnPartial` method marked with `[HttpPost]` is called because the request was in a POST context. What you want is, You just need the view without the action executing even when POSTing. The above code does that. It renders the view without calling the action method. MVC3 is sort of a stupid servent : It only knows that it should call the Action method marked with `[HttpPost]` when the request is in a post context. It doesn't know that the request is in a post context for another action (index) and not this one (logonpartial). So now you can remove this method

```
public ActionResult LogOnPartial()
        {
            return PartialView();
        }
```

which will no longer be used.

Note that you need to change the account controller's LogOnPartial Method to return
`return RedirectToAction("Index","Home");` instead of `return PartialView(model);` on successful login. And on FAILURE you cannot render a partialview as you have coded. You must return an entirely new View. It must neither be index nor LogonPartails - just return `return View("Login_Error_View");` which has its own layout. Otherwise it will be difficult to control the workflow.

Comment: the login already in its form but still the problem displayed and the DataAnnotations model binder return required field errors??Is there is a way to tell witch submit button is clicked?

Comment: Have you checked the rendered HTML to see of two separate, non-nested form tags are created? One form is for login and another form is for feedback. They should not overlap or be nested. Let me know if this is so.

Comment: Paste all your related views in http://pastebin.com/ or somewhere so I can look at it. Often people put a form in the layout file and one more form in the partial view - such nesting is probably causing your errors

Comment: Im editing my answer now. You have rendered a form inside another form. Wait a sec.

Comment: I remove this form from the layout(<form id="form1" runat="server" method="post">) and validation problem still exist?

Comment: So when you submit feedback, the login model gets validated, EVEN after removing the form1 form tag?

Comment: change this line `@using (Html.BeginForm()){Html.RenderAction("LogOn", "Account");}` to `Html.RenderAction("LogOn", "Account");` because Logon Action itself renders a form if not authenticated.

Comment: And remove this line `</url:form>` line 156. It has no opening element.

Comment: I do all that and still the problem exist

Comment: Your logon form should not get submitted when you are submitting your feedback form. Try to look at the rendered HTML and make sure they are two separate forms not nested inside any other. I may be able to help you if you more if your project is open source, and hosted in github or google code or codeplex

Comment: I create simple project that produce the problem, create new mvc3 internet application and here is the files code http://pastebin.com/Gtjut3h9

Comment: Finally I found an answer! It was difficult .. Ill edit the answer once again.

Comment: Note that on an errored login you need to go to a new page entirely. Else the index action will start showing errors when you have a login error.